# Why is my python discord bot suddenly duplicating responses to commands

Tags: python, discord.py

Some people were using my bot on a server I am a part of, and for some reason, the bot suddenly started duplicating responses to commands. Basically, instead of doing an action once, it would do it twice. I tried restarting it multiple times which didn't work, and I know it isn't a problem with my code because it was working perfectly well a few seconds ago. It probably wasn't lag either, because only a couple of people were using it. Any ideas on why this may be and how to fix it? I am also hosting it on repl.it, just so you know what ide Im using

Comment: ok so if i change the name of a command somehow the command doesn't duplicate itself, but when i change it back it goes back to the original problem

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you run the script and run the host at them same time so it sends the command thorught host and code. If you dont run the code but just the host and it still dupliactes it might be an error with the host or it runs somewhere else in the backround.